# Empty Interfaces in Golang

Tags: go, go-interface

**Edit**: This is **not** the right way to use interfaces in Go. The purpose of this question is for me to understand how empty interfaces work in Go.

If all types in Go implement `interface{}` (empty interface), why can't I access the `name` field in the `Cat` and `Dog` structs? How can I get access to the name field of each struct through the function sayHi()?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func sayHi(i interface{}) {

    fmt.Println(i, "says hello")

    // Not understanding this error message
    fmt.Println(i.name) //  i.name undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)
} 

type Dog struct{
    name string
}
type Cat struct{
    name string
}

func main() {
    d := Dog{"Sparky"}
    c := Cat{"Garfield"}

    sayHi(d) // {Sparky} says hello
    sayHi(c) // {Garfield} says hello
}
```

Comment: After some further research, I found this going through A Tour of Go. https://tour.golang.org/methods/15.

Comment: Interfaces specify _behaviour_ (read methods), not data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An `interface{}` is a method set, not a field set. A type implements an interface if it's methods include the methods of that interface. Since empty interface doesn't have any methods, all types implement it.

If you need to access a field, you have to get the original type:

```
name, ok:=i.(Dog).name
```

This will recover the name if `i` is a `Dog`.

Alternatively, implement a `getName()` function for both `Dog` and `Cat`, and then they will both implement the following interface:

```
type NamedType interface {
   getName() string
}
```

Then you can rewrite your function as:

```
func sayHi(i NamedType) {
   fmt.Println(i.getName()) 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't do that because interface values don't do that.

What interface values do—*regardless* of the interface type itself; it doesn't matter if the interface type is empty or not—is that they hold two things:

- the concrete type of some value (or no type); and
- the value of that concrete type (or no value).

So if some variable `v` or expression `e` has type `I` where `I` is an interface type, then you can, with some syntax, inspect either or both of these two "fields".  They're not `struct` fields so you can't just use `v.type`, but you *can* do this:

```
switch v.(type) {
case int: // the value in v has type int
case *float64: // the value in v has type float64
// etc
}
```

The `.(type)` in a `switch` means *let me look at the type field*.

Getting the actual *value* is harder, because Go more or less requires that you check the type first.  In your case, you know that `i` holds either a `Dog` or a `Cat`, so you can write:

```
var name string
switch i.(type) {
case Dog: name = i.(Dog).name
case Cat: name = i.(Cat).name
default: panic("whatever 'i' is, it is not a Dog or Cat")
}
fmt.Println(name)
```

This is pretty clumsy, and there are lots of ways to make it less clumsy, but that's always the first step: *figure out what the type is*.

Well, sometimes there's a step before the first step: *figure out whether the variable has anything at all in it.*  You do this with:

```
if i == nil {
    ...
}
```

Note, however, that if `i` has some *typed* value in it, and the type can hold nil pointers, the *value* part of `i` can be nil and yet `i == nil` will be false.  That's because `i` *does* have a *type* in it.

```
var i interface{}
var p *int
if i == nil {
    fmt.Println("i is initially nil")
}
if p == nil {
    fmt.Println("p is nil")
}
i = p
if i != nil {
    fmt.Printf("i is now not nil, even though i.(*int) is %v\n", i.(*int))
}
```

(try this on the [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Wav_vPrHtCy)).

#### This usually isn't the right way to use `interface`

Most often—there are exceptions—we don't even *try* to look at the type of some interface.  Instead, we define an interface that provides *methods*—functions we can call—that do something we need done.  See [Burak Serdar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59976953/1256452) in which the interface type has a `getName` method.  Then, instead of trying to figure out which of some limited set of types someone gave us, we just say:

```
name := i.getName()
```

to invoke the `getName` *method* on the underlying concrete value.  If `i` holds a `Dog`, that calls `func (Dog) getName() string`, which you'll need to define.  If `i` holds a `Cat`, it calls `func (Cat) getName() string`.  If you decide to add to your collection a type named `Bird`, you can define `func (Bird) getName() string`, and so on.

(Usually, the methods would be *exported* too: `GetName`, rather than `getName`.)

Answer (score 4):

Like you say, `interface{}` is an **empty** interface. How can you assume that something "empty" has a `name` field in it (`fmt.Println(i.name)`)? You can't. In fact, go doesn't support fields in interfaces, only methods.

What you can do (and there are, of course, many solutions), is to define an interface (let's call it `Pet`) which has a method returning the pet's name:

```
type Pet interface {
    getName() string
}
```

Then you can receive this interface (its object) in the `sayHi` function and use it to print the pet's name:

```
func sayHi(i Pet) {
    fmt.Println(i.getName())
}
```

Now, in order to be able to pass `Dog` or `Cat` to `sayHi()`, both of these structs have to implement the interface. So, define the `getName()` methods for them:

```
func (d Dog) getName() string {
    return d.name
}

func (c Cat) getName() string {
    return c.name
}
```

And that's it.

Answer (score -2):

It can also be implemented using switch type as below-

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func sayHi(i interface{}) {

    fmt.Println(i, "says hello")

    switch x := i.(type) {
    case Dog:
        fmt.Println(x.name)
    case Cat:
        fmt.Println(x.name)
    }

}

type Dog struct {
    name string
}
type Cat struct {
    name string
}

func main() {
    d := Dog{"Sparky"}
    c := Cat{"Garfield"}

    sayHi(d) // {Sparky} says hello
    sayHi(c) // {Garfield} says hello
}
```

Playground link - https://go.dev/play/p/p4s3_jmmbGJ